# How to mount an Arvados FUSE to a Docker container as volume

Tags: docker, fuse

I would like to add a file system view of [Arvados Keep](https://doc.arvados.org/v1.2/user/topics/keep.html) to a Docker container. I created this file system view with `arv-mount` and it is based on File System in Userspace (FUSE).

**Approach 1**

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/test/arv:/opt ubuntu:hirsute bash
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/home/test/arv': mkdir /home/test/arv: file exists.
```

**Approach 2** 
I also tried [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

```
$ docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source=/home/test/arv,target=/opt,bind-propagation=rshared ubuntu:hirsute bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": stat /home/test/arv: permission denied.
```

Both approaches I tried as non-root user (I configured Docker for [non-root users](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)) and root user.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working by

1. Adding `user_allow_other` to `/etc/fuse.conf`
2. Creating FUSE mount with `arv-mount --allow-other /home/test/arv`